# Calculate beta using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to calculate the beta of stocks based on - beta=(E(ri)-RF)/(RM-RF)
I have DF, the indexes are monthly period 
Columns are stocks (2 last columns are the RM and RF)
I wanna create new DF and insert the beta for each stock per every month.

View of DF

[image]

```
DF_copy[:] = (DF_PERMNO_RF.sub(new_DFRF.returns_RF))/DF_PERMNO_RF.iloc[:,-2]-DF_PERMNO_RF.iloc[:,-1]
```

For some reason I get this error
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (777,34106) into shape (777,32665)

Plz someone? help me... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have already defined DF_copy before this row?

Comment: Yes, of course... sorry for ignoring that

Comment: DF_PERMNO_RF has much more columns. You might need to  slicing